# python does not read the second line of the file

Tags: python

i have a text file with the below contents

```
url1,user1,xxxxxxxxx
url2,user2,yyyyyyyyy
```

I have a block of code that is supposed to get the value `xxxxxxxxx` or `yyyyyyyyy` based on the `env` value passed(`prod` or `test`)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

class test:
    def __init__(self, env):
        self.env = env

    def func(self):
        res = []
        try:
            if os.path.exists("file.txt"):
                    try:
                        with open("file.txt", 'r') as fp:
                            for line in fp:
                                print("line is " +line)
                                line_api = line.split(',')[2]
                                print(line_api)
                                res.append(line_api)
                                print(res)
                                if self.env == "prod":
                                    self.api = res[0]
                                    print(self.api)
                                else:
                                    self.api = res[1]
                                    print(self.api)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

value when `else` part is executed

```
list index out of range
```

Now when the `env` passed is `prod` the function works but when the value is `test` and the `else` part is executed the value of list `res` is only `xxxxxx`, there is only one value in list and the code `self.api = res[1]` fails. `print(res)` only prints `['xxxxxxxxxxxx\n']` but when `url` passed is `url1` `print(res)` only prints  both ['xxxxxxxxxxx\n', 'yyyyyyyyy \n']

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: So the intention is to find the respective value of a url?

Comment: @DirtyBit  the intention is to find the `api` value..i.e, the 3rd col value in the text file, value should be 1st col value(xx) if url1 and 2nd col value(yyy) if url2 is passed

Comment: Understood and posted an answer already, see if it helps?

Comment: @DirtyBit i edited my code to be more understandable

Comment: Update: the problem was with the if condition check, the if should be outside for loop.

Comment: Why are you checking the `env` in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you split each line that you read in with `line_api = line.split(',')[2]` and the `[2]` is referencing the third element that exists in that list which is `xxxxxxxxx` or `yyyyyyyyy`, then when you call `self.api = res[0]` you reference the first (and only) element in that list.

`self.api = res[1]` will always throw an error because it will never exist in the 1 element list. I'm not sure what the goal was for this else statement, but I would suggest using DirtyBit's elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

Since it is hard to debug your already excessive code, Here is a shorter snippet:

Using [`startswith()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_startswith.htm):

list.txt:

```
url1,user1,xxxxxxxxx
url2,user2,yyyyyyyyy
```

**Hence**:

```
logFile = "list.txt"    

def getUrlValue(url):
    with open(logFile) as f:
        content = f.readlines()

    # you may also want to remove empty lines
    content = [l.strip() for l in content if l.strip()]    

    for line in content:
        if line.startswith(url):
            print(line.split(',')[2])

getUrlValue("url1")
getUrlValue("url2")
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
xxxxxxxxx
yyyyyyyyy
```